# Is the castle the only place to find money?

Tags: ittle-dew

I am trying to save up enough money for the ice wand, and I keep getting told to look in the castle. I know I can find cards and heart pieces other places, so can I find money other places too, or is the castle the only place where there is money to be found?

Answer (score 1):

It is.

There is no money outside of the castle.